# No Quotes, Please. Prove me right

Tags: steganography

Remove the message to reveal the message:

> "Tonbo etoto rono thart dofo rybo eu"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have the famous

> To be or not to be

and we highlight

> "**To**n**b**o **e**t**o**to **r**o**no t**har**t** d**o**fo ry**b**o **e**u"

to get

> Not too hard for you

Comment: How did you arrive at the idea to take out that particular quote? Random chance, or was there some clue?

Comment: It was actually the first quote I could think of. And then it magically fit.

Comment: I was on this track as well, but I found that "famous" quote by working backwards .. ;)  start at the end of the text, and look for common words, that famous quote kind of starts leaping out at you :)

Comment: @Improve I weirdly arrived about the same way, looking at that quote somehow you can still see the underlying "To be or not to be", it just kind of sticks out.

Comment: The interesting part about composing the puzzle was getting a quote and a message that were about the same length and then putting them together in a way that neither leapt right off the page. The brain is incredibly good at seeing patterns.